# Capture symbol "*" as an argument in a java program

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a simple java calculator program capable of addition, multiplication, subtraction, and division.

Within Eclipse, it works perfectly. But when I try to run it on Ubuntu Terminal, the symbol "*" is not recognized as an argument.

For example, when I type: `java Calculate 7 * 8`, the program does not read in the input as three pieces of arguments.

I am curious to know the cause of this problem and possibly a fix to this.

Comment: Try `java Calculate "7 * 8"`

Comment: post your code and the command to run the program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this on most command lines, the `*` is going to be expanded to the list of files in the directory. Try escaping it with quotes...

```
java Calculate 7 "*" 8
```

or

```
java Calculate 7 '*' 8
```

Edit: Thanks @Danny Daglas

Comment: "" are good quotes to use on Windows.  '' are preferable for Ubuntu because `"*"` will still expand to "all files in the current working directory" in most Unix shells.  `'*'` will not.

Comment: On Windows the original line is still available. Unlike UNIX, that is what is passed to the process. The `java.exe` wrapper then has that parsed into bad old `argv` and `argc`. However, there isn't a standard way to get at the original line.